# Marbles in urn: probability of drawing homogeneous sample

Tags: probability

An urn has half red and half white marbles. The probability of getting all red or all white in 4 draws is 12.5% and the probability of getting all white or all red in 7 draws is 1.56%. How does one calculate these percentages without knowing the actual numbers of red and white marbles in the urn?

Comment: These numbers are incorrect unless the marbles are returned to the urn after each draw.

Comment: @whuber True, though if the number of marbles is very large, they're accurate to the quoted number of significant digits even without replacement.

Comment: Try this thought experiment: how would this procedure change if you were using (a) an urn with one red and one white ball as opposed to (b) an urn with 100 balls of each color?

Answer (score 1):

$P({\rm red}) = 0.50$

$P({\rm white}) = 0.50$

As @Whuber said, as long as the red/white ball is replaced after pulling one out (i.e. the experiment is done with replacement), then the probabilities of consecutive red/white pulls are

$P({\rm red\ red\ red\ red}) = (0.50)(0.50)(0.50)(0.50) = 0.0625$

$P({\rm white\ white\ white\ white}) = (0.50)(0.50)(0.50)(0.50) = 0.0625$

So it actually looks like you're asking about 3 straight pulls of red or white, not 4.

How many marbles are in the actual urn is irrelevant.  It only matters what the probability of  red or white is on the current pull.  If there are 30 white and 30 red or 30,000 white and 30,000 red balls in the urn, it's still 50/50 of pulling a red or a white.

Again, this is only if you're replacing the ball after pulling it out.  If not, then the probability of pulling a red or white on the next pull is dependent on what you pulled out on the last pull.

Your second question looks like it's actually for 6 straight reds or 6 straight whites, not 7.

$P({\rm red\ red\ red\ red\ red\ red}) = (0.50)(0.50)(0.50)(0.50)(0.50)(0.50) = 0.015625$.

The probability of 7 straight reds is half of that.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but wouldn't the P(all reds or all whites) be P(redredredred)+P(whitewhitewhitewhite)= .0625+.0625= .125?

Comment: yes, the chances of all white on 4 straight is .0625 and the chances of all red on 4 straight is also .0625.  so the chances of either all red or all white on 4 straight is .125.  I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume x is the number of marbes in the urn and y is the number of draws.
The number of possible scenarios is defined by the following: X^y

In the first case we draw 4 time.
So 2^4 = 16 scenarios
From 16 scenarios 2 are the cases we have all red or all white.
So the probability is:
P% = (2/16)*100% => P% = 12.5%

In the second case according to the following we have:
2^7 = 128 scenarios
P% = (2/128)*100% => P% = 1.56%